# How to send the value from a html page to js when using AngularJS directives

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a `directive` in AngulrJS.

Below is my `sample.html`

```
<uservalue user="user.userlist" change-user='user()'></uservalue >
```

below is my uservalue library

```
app.directive('uservalue ', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            user:'=',
            changeUser: '&',
            readonly: '@',
            valueChange: '='
            isClickable: '@'
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,  
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/template.html',
    });
}
```

from here It is redirecting to `template.html`
Below is my `template.html`

```
<select><option value="">Choose user</option>
<option id = "username" data-ng-repeat="c in user" value="{{c.key}}">{{c.value}} </option>
</select>
```

I can able to display all the users in `sample.html` in a dropdown and on change of the value in the drop down it is going to another js i.e `user()`. Now my requirement is that I have to send the dropdown selected value to the `user()` js function.

Any suggestions !!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is more you can do with your `<select>`s.
Instead of using `<option ng-repeat="...">...`, you can use the `ngOptions` and bind your model to any object (not just strings as with "plain" `<select>`s).
E.g.:

```
<select ng-model="selectedKey" ng-options="user.key as user.value for user in users"
    <!-- Optionally add a `null` option -->
    <option value="">Choose user</option>
</select>
```

---

If you want to trigger a function whenever the selected item changes, you can use `ngChange`.
Furthermore, if you want to pass arguments to a function bound to your isolate scope using `&`, you must call the function passing an object of the form: `{argName1: argValue1, ...}`.
E.g.:

```
<!-- In the VIEW -->
...change-user="setUser(userKey)"...

/* In the DIRECTIVE's SCOPE */
...
changeUser = '&'

<!-- In the DIRECTIVE's TEMPLATE -->
<select ng-model="selectedKey" ... ng-change="changeUser({userKey:selectedKey})">
    ...
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/3Yz9L/)**.